# What does this symbol $\odot$ mean?

Tags: astronomy, notation, sun

While reading through a physics textbook, I came across the use of sub-scripted ☉s.

Here's the context:

Stars between 0.5M<sub>☉</sub> and 10M<sub>☉</sub> will evolve into **red giants**...

I'm assuming it's to do with the life-span of a star; however, I don't know exactly how.

I searched google/wikipedia however it simply stated it represented the sun

Comment: [solar mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_mass)

Comment: I *really* don't understand why this was down-voted.

Comment: I didnt downvote, but I guess the reason is that you didnt really show any research effort.

Comment: I searched google/wikipedia however it simply stated it represented the sun.

Comment: And what you found when you searched is exactly right and the answer to your question.

Comment: Which is why I resulted to this forum for an actual, contextual answer...

Comment: I do not at all believe that this symbol is not defined in the textbook previous to its use. At worst, there will be a table at the very beginning of the book.

Comment: "A Level Physics for OCR - Year 2" have a read.

Comment: I know OP asks about astronomy, but concerning the title question, FYI, in mathematics $\odot$ denotes the [symmetric tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor#Symmetric_product).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symbol in question, $\odot$, usually denotes the Sun. The solar mass, $M_\odot$, is often used as a unit of mass in astronomical/astrophysical texts. Another example is the solar luminosity, $L_\odot$.

Comment: Does 1M⊙ represent the mass of the sun?

Comment: It's exactly as it's written in the answer above. No need for a 1 in front and a subscript symbol for the sun.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, "solar mass" and "mass of the Sun" mean exactly the same thing, represented by the symbol $M_\odot$.